# What is life-continuum?

Tags: jhana, consciousness

In the book **Path Of Purification** It talks about

> The explanation of the meaning here( " talking about the five jhana mastery mostly mastety if Adverting " ) is this. When he emerges from the first jhána and first of all adverts to the applied thought, then, next to the adverting that arose interrupting the life-continuum, either four or five impulsions
>   impel with that applied thought as their object. Then there are two life-continuum
>   [consciousnesses]. Then there is adverting with the sustained thought as its
>   object and followed by impulsions in the way just stated. When he is able to
>   prolong his conscious process uninterruptedly in this way with the five jhána
>   factors, then his mastery of adverting is successful. But this mastery is found at
>   its acme of perfection in the Blessed One’s Twin Marvel (Paþis I 125), or for others on the aforesaid occasions. There is no quicker mastery in adverting than
>   that.

I'm having trouble understanding what they mean here. What iis life-continuum? It said in brackets consciousness so it's disrupting consciousness of the jhana object? What i guess they mean is once you come out of jhana use applied thought to focus on the things that intruped that jhana then once you have "applied" applied thought move to focus on the objects with sustain thought once you can do this uninterrupted you mastered adverting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

life-continuum is **Bhavanga-citta**. It's the filler thought moment/moments between every 2 thoughts/experiences. It keeps you from dying when the senses cannot provide an object to the mind. When you are in dreamless sleep, your mind mostly has Bhavanga-cittas.

It's the first thought moment in your life and the last thought moment of the previous life. It is a resultant thought moment, thus Karmicly neutral. For humans and above, it's always a result of good Karma. For hell-beings, it's a result of bad Karma.

Comment: I guess this is from the Abhidhamma?

Comment: Abhidhamma & Visuddhimagga

Comment: So when they say advert to the things that intruped that what do that mean? Since i thought it was an object but as you stated it's not

Comment: Wait could they mean you advert your attention to the things that broke your consciousness-less mind?

Comment: Yes, it just means the object that interrupted the Bhavanga process. Read this: [Mind in its passive and active forms](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/mendis/wheel322.html#citta)

Comment: Update: I fully understand this is Mastery of adverying being able to enter the jhana factors right after you emerge from yhe jhana. That what they mean by advert to that which arouse interrupting life continuum. That the jhana factors cause focussing on them will not have pauses in thought but a steady focus steam

Answer (score 0):

Life-continuum is the same kamma's fruit of one's first born mind. The life-continuum arisen by kamma to keep the fruit go on the kamma's way, such as a human birth living in a human based mind and body, or a animal birth living in a animal based mind and body.